# TikZ diagram for photography (apperture and focus rings)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles

I am preparing a class about photography, and I want to include some examples illustrating how lenses render focus based on their aperture ring. Hence, I want to create a TikZ figure that displays the image below.

[image: lens]

In particular, I am only interested in the numbers displayed below. So I want a TikZ figure I can modify that looks something like:

```
                              ft  15   10   7     5
                              m   5    3     2   1.5
------------------------------------+----+-+-<>-+-+---+--+-----
                                    16   8 4    4 8      16
16     11    8      5.6     4    2.8     2   1.4
```

Could you provide any suggestions about how to create it?

Comment: Do you have any experience with tikz? What have you tried?

Comment: In which way should the figure be modifiable? I take it that there are three scales that can be shifted (turned in the original)?

Comment: @JasperHabicht thank you for your comment. The only "fixed" part of the image is the third line of numbers (the one with the diamond). The other shift the numbers either toward left or right. Also, the two first lines are moving together (since it is just an equivalence in meters and feet).  I

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although you did not show anything you tried here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[sfdefault,condensed]{roboto}

% #1: x coordinate of bottom middle, #2: y coordinate of bottom middle
\newcommand{\dofcentermark}[2]{
        \draw[fill=white] (#1,#2) -- (#1-0.125,#2+0.28) -- (#1,#2+0.56) -- (#1+0.125,#2+0.28) -- cycle;
    }

% #1: x coordinate of dof mark, #2: y coordinate of dof mark, #3 dof mark text
\newcommand{\dofrangemark}[3]{
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}
            {\node (DOF_range)  at (#1,#2) {\phantom{1}};}
            {\node (DOF_range)  at (#1,#2) {#3};}
        \draw[-] (DOF_range) -- ++(0,0.45);
    }

% #1: move whole display in x direction, #2: move window content in x direction
\newcommand{\distancenodes}[2][0]{
        \node (ft) at (-2.8+#1,2) {ft};
        \node (m) at (-2.8+#1,1.5) {m};
        \begin{scope}
            % clipping window
            \clip[draw](-2.5+#1,1.2) rectangle (2.5+#1,2.4);
            % ft
            \node (15ft) at (-2.15+#1+#2,2) {15};
            \node (10ft) at (-1.5+#1+#2,2) {10};
            \node (7ft) at (-0.2+#1+#2,2) {7};
            \node (5ft) at (1.7+#1+#2,2) {5};
            % m
            \node (5m) at (-2.3+#1+#2,1.5) {5};
            \node (3m) at (-1.45+#1+#2,1.5) {3};
            \node (2m) at (0+#1+#2,1.5) {2};
            \node (1.5m) at (1.8+#1+#2,1.5) {1.5};
        \end{scope}
        \dofrangemark{-2+#1}{0.75}{16}
        \dofrangemark{-1.3+#1}{0.75}{}
        \dofrangemark{-0.85+#1}{0.75}{8}
        \dofrangemark{-0.58+#1}{0.75}{}
        \dofrangemark{-0.4+#1}{0.75}{4}
        \dofcentermark{#1}{0.6}
        \dofrangemark{0.4+#1}{0.75}{4}
        \dofrangemark{0.58+#1}{0.75}{}
        \dofrangemark{0.85+#1}{0.75}{8}
        \dofrangemark{1.3+#1}{0.75}{}
        \dofrangemark{2+#1}{0.75}{16}
    }

% #1: x shift of aperture ring
\newcommand{\aperturenodes}[1][0]{
        \node (f16) at  (0+#1,0) {16};
        \node (f11) at  (1+#1,0) {11};
        \node (f8) at   (2+#1,0) {8};
        \node (f5.6) at (3+#1,0) {5.6};
        \node (f4) at   (4+#1,0) {4};
        \node (f2.8) at (5+#1,0) {2.8};
        \node (f2) at   (6+#1,0) {2};
        \node (f1.4) at (7+#1,0) {1.4}; 
    }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        %\draw[fill] (0,-1) rectangle (14,3.5);     % if you uncomment these two parts it will become white on black background
        \begin{scope}%[color=white]                 % if you uncomment these two parts it will become white on black background
            \distancenodes[9]{0}
            \aperturenodes[2]
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Added better font

[image]

EDIT: Now implemented correctly calculated spacing of the DOF window numbers and easy selection of f-stop and focusing distance for the creation of the image
EDIT: Now implemented correctly calculated spacing of the DOF window numbers and easy selection of f-stop and focusing distance for the creation of the image

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xfp}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[sfdefault,condensed]{roboto}

\definecolor{almost-black}{gray}{0.1}
\definecolor{dark-gray}{gray}{0.2}
\definecolor{middle-gray}{gray}{0.5}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.7}

% #1: x coordinate of bottom middle, #2: y coordinate of bottom middle
\newcommand{\dofcentermark}[2]{
    \draw[fill=white] (#1,#2) -- (#1-0.125,#2+0.28) -- (#1,#2+0.56) -- (#1+0.125,#2+0.28) -- cycle;
}

\newcommand{\dofrangedisplaytext}{}
% #1: x coordinate of dof mark, #2: y coordinate of dof mark, #3 dof mark text
\newcommand{\dofrangemark}[3]{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}
    {\renewcommand{\dofrangedisplaytext}{\phantom{1}}}
    {\renewcommand{\dofrangedisplaytext}{#3}}
    \node (DOF_range)  at (#1,#2) {\dofrangedisplaytext};
    \draw[-] (DOF_range) -- ++(0,0.45);
}

\newcommand{\meterinfeet}[1]{\fpeval{3.28*#1}}
\newcommand{\feetinmeter}[1]{\fpeval{0.3048*#1}}

\newcommand{\dofdistancescalingfactor}{8.01}

% #1: x-offset, #2: y-offset
\newcommand{\dofdistancenodeinfty}[2]{
    \node (infty) at (#1+\fpeval{\dofdistancescalingfactor/999}, #2) {$\infty$};
}

% #1: x-offset, #2: y-offset, #3: dof-distance in meter
\newcommand{\dofdistancenodemeter}[3]{
    \node (#3m) at (#1+\fpeval{\dofdistancescalingfactor/#3}, #2) {#3};
}

% #1: x-offset, #2: y-offset, #3: dof-distance in feet
\newcommand{\dofdistancenodefeet}[3]{
    \node[color=yellow] (#3m) at (#1+\fpeval{\dofdistancescalingfactor/\feetinmeter{#3}}, #2) {#3};
}

\newcommand{\dofwindowxoffset}{}
\newcommand{\dofwindowyoffsetmeter}{1.5}
\newcommand{\dofwindowyoffsetfeet}{1.9}
\newcommand{\dofwindowyoffsetmarks}{0.85}
\newcommand{\fstopringyoffset}{0.3}

% #1: move whole display in x direction, #2: move window content to x m
\newcommand{\distancenodes}[2][0]{
    
    % meter and feet text
    \node[color=yellow] (ft) at (-2.8+#1, \dofwindowyoffsetfeet) {ft};
    \node (m) at (-2.8+#1, \dofwindowyoffsetmeter) {m};
    
    \renewcommand{\dofwindowxoffset}{#1+#2-4}
    \begin{scope}
        % clipping window
        \clip[draw](-2.5+#1,1.3) rectangle (2.5+#1,2.15);
        
        % ft labels
        \dofdistancenodefeet{\dofwindowxoffset}{\dofwindowyoffsetfeet}{60}
        \dofdistancenodefeet{\dofwindowxoffset}{\dofwindowyoffsetfeet}{25}
        \dofdistancenodefeet{\dofwindowxoffset}{\dofwindowyoffsetfeet}{15}
        \dofdistancenodefeet{\dofwindowxoffset}{\dofwindowyoffsetfeet}{10}
        \dofdistancenodefeet{\dofwindowxoffset}{\dofwindowyoffsetfeet}{7}
        \dofdistancenodefeet{\dofwindowxoffset}{\dofwindowyoffsetfeet}{5}           
        \dofdistancenodefeet{\dofwindowxoffset}{\dofwindowyoffsetfeet}{4}
        \dofdistancenodefeet{\dofwindowxoffset}{\dofwindowyoffsetfeet}{3}           \dofdistancenodefeet{\dofwindowxoffset}{\dofwindowyoffsetfeet}{2.5} 
        
        % infinity label
        \dofdistancenodeinfty{\dofwindowxoffset}{\dofwindowyoffsetmeter}        
        
        % meter labels
        \dofdistancenodemeter{\dofwindowxoffset}{\dofwindowyoffsetmeter}{15}
        \dofdistancenodemeter{\dofwindowxoffset}{\dofwindowyoffsetmeter}{7}
        \dofdistancenodemeter{\dofwindowxoffset}{\dofwindowyoffsetmeter}{5}
        \dofdistancenodemeter{\dofwindowxoffset}{\dofwindowyoffsetmeter}{3}
        \dofdistancenodemeter{\dofwindowxoffset}{\dofwindowyoffsetmeter}{2}
        \dofdistancenodemeter{\dofwindowxoffset}{\dofwindowyoffsetmeter}{1.5}
        \dofdistancenodemeter{\dofwindowxoffset}{\dofwindowyoffsetmeter}{1.2}
        \dofdistancenodemeter{\dofwindowxoffset}{\dofwindowyoffsetmeter}{1}
        \dofdistancenodemeter{\dofwindowxoffset}{\dofwindowyoffsetmeter}{0.8}
        
        % shadow
        \draw[draw=none,rectangle, left color=black, right color=dark-gray, anchor=south west, opacity=0.5] (-2.5+#1,1.3) rectangle (-2.4+#1,2.15);
        \draw[draw=none,rectangle, right color=black, left color=dark-gray, anchor=south west, opacity=0.5] (2.5+#1,1.3) rectangle (2.4+#1,2.15);       
        
        \draw[color=light-gray] (-2.5+#1,1.3) rectangle (2.5+#1,2.15);
        
    \end{scope}
    
    % top border
    \draw[fill, color=light-gray] (0,2.15) rectangle ++(#1+3.5,0.15);
    \draw[fill, color=almost-black] (0,2.15) rectangle ++(#1+3.5,0.03); 
    
    % rifling
    \foreach \x in {0,0.28,...,20}
        \draw[fill, color=middle-gray] (0+\x,2.35) rectangle ++(0.1,0.3);
        
    \dofrangemark{-\dofwindowxposition{\dofmaxfm{16}{2}}+#1}{\dofwindowyoffsetmarks}{16}
    \dofrangemark{-\dofwindowxposition{\dofmaxfm{11}{2}}+#1}{\dofwindowyoffsetmarks}{}
    \dofrangemark{-\dofwindowxposition{\dofmaxfm{8}{2}}+#1}{\dofwindowyoffsetmarks}{8}
    \dofrangemark{-\dofwindowxposition{\dofmaxfm{5.6}{2}}+#1}{\dofwindowyoffsetmarks}{}
    \dofrangemark{-\dofwindowxposition{\dofmaxfm{4}{2}}+#1}{\dofwindowyoffsetmarks}{4}
    \dofcentermark{#1}{\dofwindowyoffsetmarks-0.15}
    \dofrangemark{-\dofwindowxposition{\dofminfm{4}{2}}+#1}{\dofwindowyoffsetmarks}{4}
    \dofrangemark{-\dofwindowxposition{\dofminfm{5.6}{2}}+#1}{\dofwindowyoffsetmarks}{}
    \dofrangemark{-\dofwindowxposition{\dofminfm{8}{2}}+#1}{\dofwindowyoffsetmarks}{8}
    \dofrangemark{-\dofwindowxposition{\dofminfm{11}{2}}+#1}{\dofwindowyoffsetmarks}{}
    \dofrangemark{-\dofwindowxposition{\dofminfm{16}{2}}+#1}{\dofwindowyoffsetmarks}{16}
}

% #1: f-stop, #2: focal distance
\newcommand{\dofmaxfm}[2]{\fpeval{round(#2*\focallength^2/(\focallength^2-#1*\circleofconfusion*(#2-\focallength)),2)}} 
% #1: f-stop, #2: focal distance
\newcommand{\dofminfm}[2]{\fpeval{round(#2*\focallength^2/(\focallength^2+#1*\circleofconfusion*(#2-\focallength)),2)}}

% #1: x shift of aperture ring
\newcommand{\aperturenodes}[1][0]{
    % right rifling
    \foreach \x in {0,0.28,...,2.5}
        \draw[fill, color=middle-gray] (#1+\x,\fstopringyoffset-0.28) rectangle ++(0.1,0.58);
    
    % left rifling
    \foreach \x in {0,-0.28,...,-6}
        \draw[fill, color=middle-gray] (#1-9+\x,\fstopringyoffset-0.28) rectangle ++(0.1,0.58);      
    
    % top line
    \draw[fill, color=almost-black] (0,\fstopringyoffset+0.3) rectangle ++(#1+3.5,0.03);
    
    % aperture text
    \node (f16)  at (#1-8,\fstopringyoffset) {16};
    \node (f11)  at (#1-7,\fstopringyoffset) {11};
    \node (f8)   at (#1-6,\fstopringyoffset) {8};
    \node (f5.6) at (#1-5,\fstopringyoffset) {5.6};
    \node (f4)   at (#1-4,\fstopringyoffset) {4};
    \node (f2.8) at (#1-3,\fstopringyoffset) {2.8};
    \node (f2)   at (#1-2,\fstopringyoffset) {2};
    \node (f1.4) at (#1-1,\fstopringyoffset) {1.4};
    
    % bottom line
    \draw[fill, color=almost-black] (0,\fstopringyoffset-0.28) rectangle ++(#1+3.5,0.03);
    
}

\newcommand{\dofwindowxposition}[1]{
    \fpeval{\dofdistancescalingfactor/2-\dofdistancescalingfactor/#1}
}
\newcommand{\clipfill}[2]{
    \draw[draw=none,color=#1, fill] #2;
    \clip #2;   
}

% #2: f-stop, #3: distance in m
\newcommand{\dofscalefm}[3][8]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}[color=white]
            \clipfill{dark-gray}{(0,0) rectangle ++(#1+3.5,2.34)}
            \distancenodes[#1]{\dofwindowxposition{#3}}
            \aperturenodes[#1+\fpeval{round(ln(#2^2)/ln(2))}]
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\circleofconfusion}{0.000035}
\newcommand{\focallength}{0.05}

\begin{document}
    \verb|\dofscalefm[4.5]{1.4}{2}|
    
    \dofscalefm[4.5]{1.4}{2}
    \\

    \verb|\dofscalefm{2}{\feetinmeter{15}}|

    \dofscalefm{2}{\feetinmeter{15}}
    \\
    
    \verb|\dofscalefm{11}{\feetinmeter{3}}|

    \dofscalefm{11}{\feetinmeter{3}}
    \\
    
    \verb|\dofscalefm[4]{11}{1} |

    \dofscalefm[4]{11}{1}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice results +1